# Nifi Redis Sentinel integration

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

I'm trying to integrate Nifi with Redis in sentinel mode, as described in this tutorial:

https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/10/09/apache-nifi-redis-integration

My Redis cluster has 2 nodes, running on port 6391, and 2 sentinel, running on port 6392. It seems to work ok:

```
127.0.0.1:6392> sentinel master mymaster
 1) "name"
 2) "mymaster"
 3) "ip"
 4) "192.168.50.5"
 5) "port"
 6) "6391"
 7) "runid"
 8) "d8adfb30d836ad305b96d887dfe2beb74c435305"
 9) "flags"
10) "master"
11) "link-pending-commands"
12) "0"
13) "link-refcount"
14) "1"
15) "last-ping-sent"
16) "0"
17) "last-ok-ping-reply"
18) "626"
19) "last-ping-reply"
20) "626"
21) "down-after-milliseconds"
22) "5000"
23) "info-refresh"
24) "5796"
25) "role-reported"
26) "master"
27) "role-reported-time"
28) "56761859"
29) "config-epoch"
30) "0"
31) "num-slaves"
32) "1"
33) "num-other-sentinels"
34) "1"
```

**Nifi dataflow:**

[image: nifi]

**Redis Connection Pool:**

[image: redis]

When I run the dataflow, I get this error:

> PutDistributedMapCache[id=08e39b65-0176-1000-0000-0000185bd23e] failed
> to process session due to All sentinels down, cannot determine where
> is mymaster master is running...; Processor Administratively Yielded
> for 1 sec: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
> All sentinels down, cannot determine where is mymaster master is
> running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless hours of suffering I finally found a workaround by disabling the password in sentinel. The password to specify is that of redis, not sentinel